# How to do the DNS-Request in a local Proxy Server?

Tags: c#, http, dns, proxy

I'm writing a local Proxy server. It already works for the majority of the requests. But sometimes I have Problems when I want to resolve the Host-name. Here is what I do:

When the header of the request is received, I filter the first line out. Then I take the Request-URL (which is between the two spaces) out of that line and store it into an Uri object. After that I extract the hostname with: `string host= uri.host;`
At least I do the DNS-call: `IPAddress[] ips = Dns.GetHostAddresses(host)[0];` 
(How do I know here, which IP of the array I should take. Whats the difference between those IP's)

Like I said, for the majority of the Requests that works fine. But there are some adresses, that cannot be resolved. Here an example: When I want to open **www.gmx.net**, I first get the HTML-File ( this works fine ). After that, the Browser reloads a couple of Web-Objects like pics, javascript and so on. Those Object of course have some URL. And one of those URLs, that cannot be resolved is:   **ipv4-cout.gmx.net** .
The attempt to resolve this URL results in the warning: **The stated Host is unknown**.

Another thing I need to know is: How to handle Alias-Host-names? For example: When I enter the hostname gmx.de into the Browser, it automaticaly resolves it into www.gmx.net. I know, there are Recource Reccords on a DNS-Server with type CNAME, but I dont know how to implement this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say that they come back in the order that the DNS server sends them, I can no find no reference to any particular ordering.

[Dns.GetHostAddresses Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.dns.gethostaddresses.aspx)

In most cases, there would only be a single IP address. In the case of www.gmx.net, they do have 2 and in theory, this would mean that you would round-robin the requests.

```
www.gmx.net has address 212.227.223.5
www.gmx.net has address 212.227.223.4
```

For your information. pv4-cout.gmx.net does not resolve on my machine and would result in a 404 when accessed any other way.

gmx.de does not resolve to www.gmx.net, there is a URL redirect on the web server.

```
Connecting to www.gmx.de|212.227.223.10|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 301 Moved Permanently
Location: http://www.gmx.net/ [following]
```